# BlackBerry App World Distribution of .jad files

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde, jad, blackberry-world

I am developing an app using Eclipse Plugin with BlackBerry JRE 4.5 to support devices with OS versions 4.5 and higher. I understand that when you use a JRE version lower than 4.7 and you deploy the app to a 4.7 device or a 5.0 device, the app will run in compatibility mode and as a result the virtual keyboard would appear.

I followed [this document](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800719/What_Is_-_Compatibility_mode_on_touch_screen_BlackBerry_smartphones.html?nodeid=1487544&vernum=0) to avoid running my app in compatibility mode. I was able to generate the .JAD files for version 4.7 only after I built the app with JRE 4.7. I changed my project settings back to JRE 4.5 but I updated the 4.7 .JAD file with the configurations described in the above document. That seemed to work. so when I run my app in 4.7 simulator, I don't see the virtual keyboard. I did the same thing for version 5.0.

Question is - When I package the app and submit it to the App World, will I be able to include the .JAD file for 4.7 and .JAD file for 5.0 so that when the user downloads the app and runs it, it doens't run in compatibility mode? if not, how will I make sure that my app doesn't run in compatibility mode on 4.7 or 5.0 device? If the settings in .JAD file will be compiled in to .COD file and that is used for packaging to the App World, does that take care of things?

Please help me understand if I have to include .COD or .JAD file for each version that my app will support or if one .COD file will include the configuration settings for all the OS versions. (Please bear with my ignorance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will only be able to upload the cod files to the RIM app store.

You will be able to upload a different set of cod files based on the OS. So you can compile a version of your app for OS 4.7.

Comment: Thanks, Ray. Do you know if there is way for me to translate touch events to trackball events in code when running in Non-Compatibility mode? I am guessing the events/api references for touch events will not be available in 4.5. In that case, would I have to write a separate app or something for OS versions 4.7 and higher?

Comment: Correct they are not available in 4.5, you can use preprocessing to keep the touch events in the same codebase http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/12002/Specifying_preprocessor_directives_657636_11.jsp also see this doc for overriding the touchevent in 4.7 and above http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/13222/CS_Adding_simple_touch_event_handling_to_app_705068_11.jsp