# BlackBerry Non-Compatibility Mode translate touch events

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde, compatibility-mode

I am forcing my app (developed in JRE 4.5) to run in non-compatibility mode for OS versions 4.7 and higher so that the virtual keyboard would not take up half of the screen space.

Now, when I test my app in 4.7 or 5.0 simulator, I see that the touch events are not working. Is there way to handle touch events in code so that I can translate it in to trackball events when running in Non-compatibility mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the comments on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493660/blackberry-app-world-distribution-of-jad-files) for answers